# Make Angular mat-dialog modal listen to keyboard combinations

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have a dialog modal with an input inside it .
[image]

I would add accessibility to it.

I do it already using `dialogRef.keydownEvents`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dialogRef.keydownEvents().subscribe(event => {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      this.cancel();
    }
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.validate();
    }
  });
}
```

The problem now is when user tape a text and push `Enter` to make a line break, the modal get validated then closed.

I would like to make user do a line break using `shift+Enter` without validating the modal ( because of `if (event.key === "Enter")`)

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried:  if (event.key === "Enter" && !event.shiftKey) ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, try this way:

```
if (event.key === "Enter" && !event.shiftKey) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  this.validate();
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: It prevents default actions of `textarea`, so line-breaking won't be triggered until you use `Shift + Enter`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault